# Count of combinations for case-sensitive string

Tags: string, math, numbers, combinations, factorial

As I remember, the count of combinations equal n!

But, for I example I have string "abc". I want to get all the combinations with different registry: aBc or ABc etc

So, abc is 3 chars. 3! = 1 * 2 * 3 = 6.
But, if I shall try manually do this work - I'll get 8 variations:

1 abc 
2 Abc
3 aBc
4 abC
5 ABc
6 aBC
7 AbC
8 ABC

So, it looks like, that answer it 2^3 = 8, but what is 2 ? 3 - is the count of registries in string. what is 2 ? count of registry variants?

Comment: `abc` and `ABC` aren't in different registry, so you have `8-2=6`.

Comment: To calculate the number of combinations in *different* registry: `N = c^n - c`, where `c` is the number of cases (`2` - lower, upper) and `n` is the number of elements (`3`).

Comment: formula: a^(n-i), where a is count of variations of registry ( small or big letter or more variants for another tasks ) where n - is count of chars in string and where i is count of int in string, because int can't be small or big and it not taken into account ( ab1c or Ab1c and etc )

Comment: abc and ABC - are different for many programming languages ( like C#, if you mean Visual Basic - you are right, because VB isn't case-sensitve, but C# is! )!

string a = "ABC"; string b = "abc"; if (a == b) ; - try!

Comment: you should describe your task exacly: do you need **different** cases combination, or **all** the combinations?

Comment: and what so? all - can't be different?

Comment: `abc` and `ABC` as strings are different for all the programming languages I know. But they are not in different registry, because all the letters in `abc` and `ABC` are in the same registry. To include same-registry strings in combinations, use `c^n` where `n` is the number of varying elements (to exclude integers and everything else, which doesn't have lower/upper case).

Comment: But they are not in different registry, because all the letters in abc and ABC are in the same registry####### Why they are same? As you have showed small letters and big one by your words, how they can be different , if they are in different cases?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to know for a fixed string how many possible combinations there are with respect to writing the fixed string in mixed capitalization. You are not interested in real permutations of the source string, i.e. you don't wan't to take into account that for abc there is also acb, cab, cba etc. Yes?

If so, for 1 letter we have

```
a A
```

for two letters

```
ab Ab aB AB
```

and for three letters

```
abc Abc aBc abC ABc aBC AbC ABC
```

and so on. If that's the case, then the solution is quite simple if you choose the right underlying model. As you may have noticed, the outcome is regardless of the character sequence we choose - so why not choose all `a`'s:

```
a A
aa aA Aa AA
aaa aaA aAa aAA Aaa AaA AAa AAA
```

The pattern is that for each character we have two choices available, either uppercase or lowercase, either set or not set... either 1 or 0 - simply replace a with 0 and A with 1 to get:

```
0 1
00 01 10 11
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

That is actually binary counting! So for n letters the number of possible combinations will be equal to 2^n.

Comment: @emboss- I could be wrong about this, but from the discussion in the comments I think the OP wants to filter out the binary values 00..00 and 11..11.

Comment: I'm also not a 100% sure, I was just going by the fact that he listed both in the initial example (`1 abc 2 Abc 3 aBc 4 abC 5 ABc 6 aBC 7 AbC 8 ABC`). If what you say is right, then your solution is the right one... Hopefully he will tell us :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I see what you're saying.  If I understand you correctly, you are looking to find all possible ways of capitalizing the letters in a string such that all of the letters aren't of the same case - that is, given abc, you'd produce

```
abC aBc aBC Abc AbC ABc
```

But not

```
abc ABC
```

Because all letters in those versions have the same case.

If this is what you'd like, the number of ways you can do this in a nonempty string of length n is given by 2<sup>n</sup> - 2.  Intuitively, the rationale behind this is as follows.  Given a string of n letters, there are 2<sup>n</sup> different ways to capitalize all of the letters in that string, since for each character independently of the rest, that letter can be in one  of two states (upper case or lower case).  If you consider all of those combinations, there are exactly two that you want to disallow - the version where all letters are upper-case, and the version where all letters are lower-case.

In your question, you mentioned that the number of combinations of an n-element sequence is n!.  This is not quite right.  There are n! *permutations* of an n-element sequence (assuming each element is distinct).  For example, there are 3! = 6 permutations of the sequence abc:

```
abc  acb  bac  bca  cab  cba
```

The fact that there are six ways to capitalize a three-letter sequence without giving all letters the same capitalization and that there are six permutations of abc is a complete coincidence.  If you look at more terms of the series, you can see that they only match at two locations (2 and 3):

```
                                    n = 1   2   3   4   5   6
Permutations (n!)                       1   2   6   24  120 720
Mixed-case capitalizations (2^n - 2)    0   2   6   14  30  62
```

If you allow for more cases than just upper and lower (say, k different versions), then you can generalize this to get the value k<sup>n</sup> - k, since there are k<sup>n</sup> different combinations, of which k of them will all have the same capitalization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have found some erros in our algo.
Let's look at my new version:
1). counting all combo - n! ( without case in 1-st step )
2). then, let's get value by using formula ( count of combo one type of char ): a^n-i , where a - registry count ( small/big ) in our situation always - 2, n - symbols count , i - count of numbers.
3). then multiply like this: n! * ( a^(n-i) ) and get the count of combo

but, there is a trouble, if string = "aaa111", even 6! will give us similiar combinations , but more count ( there will be many equaled combo ), so it's need to use check while counting